# ispconfig3 mailserver

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have been installing ispconfig3 on ubuntu 12.04 what usually configures the mail server as well postfix/dovecot. Creating mailboxes and testing theme no email is going to be droped. My syslog has the following content

```
lda(test@mydomain): Fatal: setresgid(5000(vmail),5000(vmail),5000(vmail)) failed with euid=5000(vmail): Operation not permitted
```

I have been searchin hours to fix this permission issue and I still get not get to work

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ispconfig3 for last 3 years without any problem.

Have you properly followed [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3) if you are using Apache.

You can also try `chown -R vmail:vmail /var/vmail/` to at least correct the permission problem and check if it works.